# Does Spell Perfection allow Quicken Spell to reduce a spell's casting time?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, feats, metamagic

The [Quicken Spell](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/metamagic-feats/quicken-spell-metamagic-final/) metamagic feat lets you cast certain spells as a swift action (instead of a standard action). This causes the spell's slot to increase by +4 levels.

The [Spell Perfection](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/spell-perfection/) feat has several benefits, including the following:

> Pick one spell which you have the ability to cast. Whenever you cast that spell you may apply any one metamagic feat you have to that spell without affecting its level or casting time, as long as the total modified level of the spell does not use a spell slot above 9th level.

The text says "affecting" the casting time, rather than "increasing".  So how does this interact with Quicken Spell, which normally reduces the casting time?

Can the spell be cast as a swift action (as per Quicken) without the +4 spell slot increase?

Or is the spell's casting time unchanged, thereby negating the benefits of Quicken Spell?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The rules, as written, are written poorly. Yes, Spell Perfection negates the benefit of Quicken Spell. Which is complete and utter nonsense, and should be ignored. Even if, and I very much doubt it, Paizo intended Spell Perfection to negate the benefit of Quicken Spell, that’s stupid and should be ignored. Special, counter-intuitive exceptions like that should be called out explicitly in the text, and usually are; RAW that’s not actually necessary here, but applying a little bit of context here suggests it normally would be and its absence is glaring.

Comment: Just to play devil's advocate, it may have been intended that you cannot combine achieve Quickened Spells with Spell Perfection (for instance, it may have been considered too powerful for the feat). You could still Quicken spells that you have Spell Perfection for (and apply another Metamagic with the benefits) but being able to cast your "perfected spell" as a Swift Action every round at-spell-level might have seemed to be too much. Of course, it was probably just poorly written and intended to account for Spontaneous Casters.

Comment: @Ifusaso I addressed that already in the answer: “Even if, and I very much doubt it, Paizo intended Spell Perfection to negate the benefit of Quicken Spell, that’s stupid and should be ignored.”

Comment: @KRyan While I appreciate (and agree with) the commentary, I am looking for a strict RAW explanation. Could you edit so that the RAW-backed answer is separate and distinct from the rest?

Comment: @MikeQ That is nowhere in your question, you might want to update that. Anyway, I establish the RAW in the first line (at least my screen), the second sentence. There is nothing more to be said on the subject, I don’t think. Are you just asking for a paragraph break between that and the rest?

Comment: @KRyan In that case, the answer is fine as is. I was hoping for some errata, or FAQ, or overlooked rule to address the feat's wording. But apparently Paizo has not accounted for spontaneous casters here.

Answer (score 0):

According to RAW Spell Perfection won't benefit from Quicken Spell and Heightened Spell because it doesn't change time and level of spell. These are two most powerful metamagic feats and are mentioned in all guides with regards to Spell Perfection though.

It is possible that the wording is a mistake and it was intended for spontaneous casters but it is possible that it is an intended feature that limits its power.

If we check similar ability, [Mimic Metamagic](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/alternative-rule-systems/occult-adventures/occult-classes/PSYCHIC/#TOC-Major-Amplifications), it specificially adresses an issue with Quicken Spell:

> If the metamagic feat alters the spell’s casting time in a different way than the standard rules for a spontaneous caster using a metamagic feat (as in the case of Quicken Spell), it changes the casting time accordingly

Lack of this correction in Spell Perfection description makes me sure that it is an intended feature. On the other hand, Mimic Metamagic still fails to address issue with Heighten Spell, so according to RAW Mimic Metamagic shouldn't work with Heighten Spell